Spark append outputmode doesn't close previous tumbling window?
I have one text file that looks like this:
a.txt
-----
John,100

I have the following spark app:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructField, StringType, StructType

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SumScoresByPerson") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Define the input path for the text files (directory)
input_path = "./data"

schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("score", StringType(), True)
])


streaming_df = spark.readStream \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("header", "false") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv(input_path)

# Split the single 'value' column into 'name' and 'score' and trim spaces
streaming_df = streaming_df.withColumn("name", F.col("name")) \
                           .withColumn("score", F.col("score").cast(IntegerType())) \
                           .withColumn("timestamp", F.current_timestamp())

# Debug: print intermediate results to verify data before aggregation
debug_query = streaming_df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .start()

# Perform aggregation (sum) on the 'score' column, grouping by 'name' with a watermark
aggregated_df = streaming_df \
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "5 seconds") \
    .groupBy(F.window(F.col("timestamp"), "30 seconds"), F.col("name")) \
    .agg(F.sum("score").alias("total_score"))

# Write the output (total scores per person) to the console in append mode
aggregated_query = aggregated_df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
    .format("console") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .start()

# Wait for the queries to terminate
aggregated_query.awaitTermination()

I start the app and I can see output from debug_query stream to console showing what's in a.txt. All good. However, aggregated_query stream shows an empty batch.
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+-----------------------+
|name|score|timestamp              |
+----+-----+-----------------------+
|John|100  |2024-10-15 14:48:11.799|
+----+-----+-----------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+------+----+-----------+
|window|name|total_score|
+------+----+-----------+
+------+----+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+------+----+-----------+
|window|name|total_score|
+------+----+-----------+
+------+----+-----------+

I then run cp a.txt b.txt in the cli. I now see:
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+-----------------------+
|name|score|timestamp              |
+----+-----+-----------------------+
|John|100  |2024-10-15 14:48:47.647|
+----+-----+-----------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+------+----+-----------+
|window|name|total_score|
+------+----+-----------+
+------+----+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+
|window                                    |name|total_score|
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+
|{2024-10-15 14:48:00, 2024-10-15 14:48:30}|John|100        |
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+

The window field in batch 3 has the timestamp of when the spark app was started. This means Batch 3 is coming from reading a.txt. I don't see b.txt at all in the console. I wait for more than 2 minutes and nothing appears in my console. The only way I can seem to force spark to output what it sees in b.txt is by inserting more data i.e. cp b.txt c.txt. But then I run into the same problem in that the contents of c.txt don't show up in the console.
Just to be sure, I waited 5 minutes and created c.txt with this content:
Cena,999

I then see this in my console:
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+-----------------------+
|name|score|timestamp              |
+----+-----+-----------------------+
|Cena|999  |2024-10-15 14:55:59.362|
+----+-----+-----------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 4
-------------------------------------------
+------+----+-----------+
|window|name|total_score|
+------+----+-----------+
+------+----+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 5
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+
|window                                    |name|total_score|
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+
|{2024-10-15 14:48:30, 2024-10-15 14:49:00}|John|100        |
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+

If I now dump another text file called d.txt with this content:
Ivory,777
I then see this in my console:
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+-----+-----+-----------------------+
|name |score|timestamp              |
+-----+-----+-----------------------+
|Ivory|78   |2024-10-15 14:56:58.972|
+-----+-----+-----------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 6
-------------------------------------------
+------+----+-----------+
|window|name|total_score|
+------+----+-----------+
+------+----+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 7
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+
|window                                    |name|total_score|
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+
|{2024-10-15 14:56:00, 2024-10-15 14:56:30}|Cena|999        |
+------------------------------------------+----+-----------+

It appears as though the append outputMode only closes / evaluates when to close a result table / tumbling window when new data arrives. This is despite having a trigger with a processingTime of 5 seconds. How do I force this to work?
My goal is this:

I have data that is submitted at random intervals in the day.
I want to process a day's worth of data in a single batch (need to do some aggregations).
I want to immediately send that output to a sink for further work downstream.

But because Spark seems to always be 1 batch behind, step #3 will always be 24 hours behind. How can I get this to work properly?

I figured it out. In order to understand this behaviour you must first understand the distinction between event time and processing time.
With outputmode = Append, Spark only closes a window when it sees data with event time > tumbling window border + watermark. If watermark is 5minutes and tumbling window is 10mins then Spark will only close the time window of 11:00 - 11:10 when it sees an event with event time >= 11:10 (tumbling window border) + 5 minutes (watermark). And once the window closes, you will see it being emitted as a batch.
